# Tackling freeloader problem of a "group auction"

Tags: game-theory, auction-theory

Not sure what to call these, which is a part of the problem, as I'd imagine there's plenty of literature on this.

So, consider the following game:

Three players, A, B and C. All of them having finite but sufficient funds.

There is a yes/no decision to be made. Which ever option has the most funds behind it wins. A thinks YES should win and B and C prefer NO. All parties know what the others want. B has a slightly higher utility for getting NO to win (and again all parties know this), and for both this is more important than for A.

A bets \$1000 on YES. Since C knows B needs NO to win, C abstains from contributing to NO side and just let's B to bump the collective offer to \$1001 -> NO wins even without C:s contribution.

Any ideas how to tackle the problem or pointers to literature? The auction can be designed in any way really, but the players will be aware of each others utilities.

Goal is to have a game where the bets from both B and C are in propotion w their utilities of making NO to happen.

Comment: Messed up the formatting and no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Put a backslash (\\) in front of the dollar signs.

Comment: Do people lose the money they bet if their desired outcome does not win?

Comment: No, it's an auction. However this is not a strict requirement in the system being built and it can be changed too.

Comment: If $B$ is willing to contribute all of the NO offer, I don't think there is any incentive to force them to contribute less.

Comment: Yup and that's the problem. What I'm asking for is modifications of the game that could help the issue. Literature refs would help too.